# How to map EF-core model with external table

Tags: sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, external-tables

I have defined an External Table using the below script:

```
create external table [dbo].[MyExternalTable]
( [MyExternalTableId] [tinyint] not null,
  [Status] [nvarchar](50) not null,
  [Description] [nvarchar](200) null)
with
( 
data_source = MyElasticDBQueryDataSrc,
SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo',           -- external table schema
OBJECT_NAME = 'MyExternalTable'       -- name of table in external database
);
go
```

How can I map this external table with the EF-Core model?

I tried below in my DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<MyExternalTable>()
          .ToView("MyExternalTable");
}
```

But when I use it, it hrows exception ***Invalid Object Name'MyExternalTable'***

```
public async Task TryGetBillPayment()
        {
            var results =
                    await _dbContext
                        .MyExternalTable
                        .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM MyExternalTable")
                        .ToListAsync();
        }
```

But if I execute the below query directly from SQL Server Management Studio, it works:

```
select * from MyExternalTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to scaffold those external tables as a separate DB context pointing directly to the other database.